# Problem importing categories and sub-categories

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms

I have an array with the categories and sub-categories I want to import to the "campsite-district-county" taxonomy.
My sub-categories are not being inserted with the correct parent. They're being inserted on the root level.
After some investigation I come across the information that I needed to clear the taxonomy cache after each insert, so I did but I still have the same problem.

```
$dist[]=array('Açores','Angra do Heroísmo');
$dist[]=array('Açores','Corvo');
$dist[]=array('Aveiro','Águeda');
$dist[]=array('Aveiro','Anadia');
foreach($dist as $d) {
    $i++;
    if(is_array($d)) {
        if ($parent_term=term_exists(trim($d[0]), 'campsite-district-county')) {
            //do nothing - let's add the county bellow
        } else {
            //Adds district
            $parent_term=wp_insert_term(trim($d[0]), 'campsite-district-county');
            delete_option("campsite-district-county");
            wp_cache_flush();
            echo '<h1>'.trim($d[0]).'</h1>';

        }
        $id_parent=intval($parent_term['term_id']);
        echo '<p>*'.$id_parent.'*</p>';
        //Add county
        $child_term=wp_insert_term(trim($d[1]), 'campsite-district-county', array('parent', $id_parent));
        delete_option("campsite-district-county_children");
        wp_cache_flush();
        echo '<p>'.trim($d[1]).'</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in your PHP. This `array('parent', $id_parent)` will produce numeric array with two values - string `parent` and value of `$id_parent`.

What you actually need is `array( 'parent' => $id_parent )` which will produce correct associative array with one entry of key `parent` and value `$id_parent`.

Comment: I was just going to delete this post because I found out the error. THANKS!